Can I install all Angular dependencies globally?
I'm starting to learn Angular for SPAs, coming from a Python/Django background, with almost no Node.js experience. I already installed @angular/cli globally using npm, since I intend to use it in a few future projects. My plan is to use a Angular frontend with Django Rest Framework for REST API calls.
I started a new Angular project with ng new, but it seems that for each project I do this it downloads all Angular dependencies into a local node_modules folder, taking 270 MB of disk space.
I wonder if I can just intall all Angular dependencies globally. If I'm understanding correctly, the final result of compiling my angular project should just be some HTML, CSS and JS files, which I will serve using Apache and Django's url scheme. I don't see why I would need all dependencies on the project folder.
I googled it and found no clear answer for a begginer. I know it is a good practice to keep specific versions of depencies, like using Virtual Environments for Python. But say I don't care about this for now, is there a way to install and use those dependencies globally?

to avoid duplication ~200+ MB in each project, check pnpm here it uses symlinks to shared deps, "drop-in" replacement for npm.

No unfortunately  you can't.
Tools like npm dedupe or try pnpm, can be used which saves space by sharing dependencies across projects.
